# Primefaces fileupload is not opening "file choose dialog" on IE9

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I see abnormal behavior of fileUpload component on IE9 (it wokrs well on Chrome & Mozilla). When p:fileUpload is put p:dialog, file chooser dialog is not opened unless user double clicked the button, this behaviour on IE<=9 only.

Very simple code sample:

FileUploader.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head></h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlg').show()" value="open"></p:commandButton>
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                <p:fileUpload value="#{UtilityView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" />
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

I tried to change CSS as suggested in some posts and tried to fire click event programmatically when user clicked once but all of that didn't help!
Your suggestions are welcomed.

Primefaces version: 5.3

Comment: Try forcing your browser in non-compatibility mode!!!

Comment: I have tested your code in IE8 and IE9. It works for me with just one click on "Browse" button.